# How can I destroy the stupid Duck?

Tags: support

**Recently I see all the time this stupid Duck with the bubble "Can I help?".
It is really annoying.**

I tried to delete it. I right-clicked it, go to settings, it just doesn't go away.

I am not sure how interpersonal this question is about the duck. But I am pretty sure a person invented it and this person probably thinks it's funny.

No, it's not funny! It's annoying!

**How can I delete the Duck?**

Comment: Maybe someone can start a survey somewhere how many people like this stupid duck and how many find it annoying. Maybe I am just to old for this s#%#.

Comment: @JessK: I don't really care if it is closed. But maybe someone should remind the people in charge that they don't do a stupid duck next year again.

Comment: It's just for April fools. I highly doubt they're going to stop doing April Fools things ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JessK. No longer needed isn't a close reason though.

Comment: @NVZ then I'd probably just call it off topic because it's nothing that actually exists.

Answer (score 8):

Just click on "I hate this duck", once you have talked to it and it will be gone.

[image]

Now click on "Goodbye Duck".

[image]

However, you have to do it on each site. Because SE has deployed 172 ducks and you have to hate each one of them to make them go away. ;-)

Comment: I don't have a microphone connected to my PC so I can't talk to the duck. And in general I am not in the habit of talking to ducks. And yes, I know, you are just the messenger and I don't blame you.

Comment: You don't have to use a microphone to talk. Even you keep silent while it's listening, the result will be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Other users have also stated that they dislike [Stack Exchange's April Fool's Day prank](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308564/274942). Fortunately, as is often the case, there's a way around it. Possibly as a nod to [a similar request during Winter Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245149/274942), you can [disable the duck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308570/274942) after letting it quack once, then clicking ["I hate this duck"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308574/274942). You will no longer see the duck.

Alternatively, you could wait for it to vanish, which it should do fairly soon. April 1st is already over for most of the world. But this is quicker, I guess.

Comment: April 1st already over and duck still there. I dont think is an april fool thing

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It is indeed temporary; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308690/274942 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308618/274942.